# Are there well known patterns to use for creating method chaining in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to implement method chaining in javascript?

```
function CONSTRUCT(){
    this.func1=function(insert_ob){insert_ob.appendTo=this;/*other code*/};
    this.func2=function(...){};
    this.func3=function(...){};

}

function My_Object_Creator(){this.appendTo=null;}

object1=new CONSTRUCT();
my_object=new my_Object_Creator();
object1.func1(my_object).func2().func3();
```

I know I can adjust those functions to in the constructor to achieve it but I want to know if there are some well-known methods or patterns one should follow while creating method chaining possibility in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to method chain is to return `this` (or a reference to the object).

Comment: That's not the only way to method chain at all

Comment: @TJHeuvel try `"asd".split("").reverse().join()` all of those are not only different objects but objects of different types

Comment: @Esailija that isn't what the OP is asking.

Comment: Also, you could return other (new?) instances or private variables, not only the `this` object that a method was called on.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I could not find the good reference on how to accomplish the method chaining in my code so I was expecting somebody could point me in a right direction on how it is done.

Comment: @DanielA.White He is asking how to do [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) isn't he? how is that unclear

Comment: @Esailija and thats the basic case is.

Comment: @Esailija: You are absolutely right. I want to know how to do method chaining in a proper way. crude way using some brute force, I think I can manage but proper way that can enhance code-reusability, I don't know.